# Allowing one user to access C drive whilst restricting others

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

In our group policy, there is a Staff Lockdown policy which uses the Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Explorer key to restrict users' access to C: drives.

I would like to be able to allow a specific user to access the C drive of a specific machine (or the C: drive of all machines if that is easier).

What is the easiest / most appropriate way to acheive this?

The purpose of the question is to allow the user to install Dropbox locally on their machine since the Dropbox installer complains when a network drive is chosen as a destination.

Thanks.

Comment: I presume that there is no 'install for everyone' option in the Dropbox installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would find the dropbox EXE and add permissions to it to be able to read the full C drive. Leave all other permissions exactly as they are, but add one permission.

Comment: How would i do this? Grant the user the Full Control permission on that file?

Comment: They should only need Read and Execute permissions on the exe file.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want to break a (relatively sane) policy of not letting users muck about on their C: drive -- plus as a general rule Users should not install software - Administrators install software for them.

You should be installing DropBox for your users (you can use one of several remote deployment tools available for Windows to do this - If you're managing several systems you probably have one of these in place already) and letting them configure their DropBox account.
The DropBox installer supports a silent (`/S`) option to help you out.

Comment: I understand the policy is sane. I should clarify- I am installing the software. As an administrator, I can install to the c: drive fine, but when my user logs on, since their access is restricted, Dropbox breaks. Dropbox is only going to be installed on this one machine